# Is there a simple way to hash in Java?

Tags: java, hash

I have some String I'd like to hash using the SHA-256 way. I looked a bit on the internet and to my great surprise, I can't find a simple way to do so.
I'm aware of the `MessageDigest` class wich seems to provide everything I need except one thing : a method like this : `String hash256(String txt)`
I also know there are ways to do so (for instance : [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-sha-hashing-example/)) but I'm reluctant to writing more than one line for something probably already existing. Do you guys know if such a thing exists ?

EDIT : it looks like I wasn't clear enough. Is there an existing method equivalent to the following code in JDK ?

```
public String hash256(String txt){
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    sha.update(txt.getBytes());
    byte[] digest = sha.digest();
    return bytesToString(digest);
}
```

Comment: Btw, that dup wasn't hard to find: google "java SHA256" and it's the top hit. No sure what you meant by "I searched the web" :/

Comment: @Bohemian As i said, I want to know if there is a jdk method wich can hash a String to a String. The examples you provide give me bytes (I know how to treat them, but I'd rather not recode something already existent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DigestUtils.sha256()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha256Hex%28java.lang.String%29) from Apache Commons Library.

Comment: Is there no JDK equivalent ?

Comment: You can see the jdk equivalent in Dodd10x's answer. You might as well do a FXMUtils class to write up the method that you want.

Comment: Not really what I want, but I guess that's the best I can get, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
md.update(stringAsbytes);
stringAsBytes = md.digest();
```

Then convert the bytes to a string.  Make sure you specify the string encoding.

Comment: The point of my question is : is there an existing method doing that all (and not just hashing to bytes) ?

Comment: The point of my answer was to show you how simple it was to do what you wanted with the existing API.  There isn't a single line solution to every problem.